# Is it possible to use binary encoding for Http and XML/SOAP encoding for TCP communication in WCF

Tags: c#, .net, wcf, soap

I understand that Most common encodings for WCF are basicHttpBinding and wsHttpBinding, which are both based around SOAP/XML, but is there is any way in WCF to send SOAP/XML over TCP(netTCPBiding) and vicerversa i.e. Binary encoded data over Http. If Yes how can I do this in my WCF application

Answer (score 2):

netTcpBinding uses [binary encoding](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms731343.aspx) by default. If you need to use SOAP over TCP there are a few solutions available. One of them is this offering:
http://www.noemax.com/global/press_releases/september_24_2007.html

Comment: Can't we do it with custom binding in wcf configuration file with binary  encoding tag

Answer (score 0):

We can set as binary encoding by using custombinding attribute in wcf configuration file.